# Accidently Formated a 16gb flash drive as a partition?! help!

Tags: usb, flash, partitioning, format, drive

I have a 16gb flash drive that I formatted. Now all of a sudden when I connect it to my PC, it neither mounts nor gives any indication that a flash drive is inserted. But when I open `Disks` from the  dash , it is there.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _formatted_, specifically?

Comment: Can you show the output of `sudo parted /dev/sdX print`, where `/dev/sdX` is replaced by the actual disk descriptor which you can see e.g. in the Disks window, please?

Comment: well i opened up the dash typed disks, selected the 16gb usb drive, clicked the menu and clicked 'Format' . i chose the faster formating option, then it unmounted and disapeared.

Comment: dont know what you just said there..i apologize, as i am new to this problem but ill screenshot the window hehe.

Comment: The screenshot says `Mounted at /media/producer/16gb drive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you formatted the device instead of a partition, you wiped out the partition table.  Now you can use the device, treating it like a big file, it will mount with a loop option, but that's almost never what is wanted.  Assuming there are no files on the device to save, just use a disk partitioning tool, like fdisk or gdisk, to put a new partition table (DOS type)  on the device, then add a new (primary) partition (Microsoft Basic Data for a FAT filesystem), and format a FAT filesystem on that.
  The specific commands will vary depending upon which disk tool you use.

Comment: You can also install and use **gparted**, with a graphical user interface, which makes it easier to use (but it does the same thing as parted and very similar things as fdisk and gdisk).